# Single Sign On with spring social

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I need single login on my 2 modules. Currently these 2 modules are different and using the same database. Currently I implemented spring social in both the modules for facebook and twitter login. but if I logged in one module and go to module 2, I have to do login again.

so how I can authenticate the user once. and get the authentication in other module.

I need something which is compatible with Spring Social.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your modules to authenticate with CAS, and then configure CAS to allow delegated authN to FB and Twitter?